# Updating widget frequently using alarm manager

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager

I have a widget that I need to update frequently with new content only while the device is awake.

I will use an alarm manager for this and set alarm type to either ELAPSED_REALTIME or RTC, as suggested on "App Widgets" guidelines on android developer site.

The problem is that I need to update the widget every 5 seconds (probably configurable) while the screen is on.

Wherever I searched people say that 5 seconds is insane, but I haven't yet really understand if this is gonna be a problem if I update only when the device is awake. Is there a different approach I can take to this problem? How clock widgets do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While experimenting I realized that when the screen goes off the alarm still triggers.
It stops triggering only when the device goes into deep sleep, in which case 5 seconds are too few anyway for the device to have time to go into sleep.

So what I did is filter the SCREEN_ON broadcast and schedule the alarm every 5 seconds. Then filter SCREEN_OFF broadcast and cancel the alarm.